# How to insert the words of a file in a list?

Tags: python, list, file, words

im programming in Python and I have next functions:

```
def devPalabras(nombreF):
    """Receive a file and returns each word in the file
        syntax: palabra.devPalabras(<fichero.txt>)"""

    if str(nombreF):
        file=open(nombreF,'r')
    else:
        return -1
    data = file.readlines()
    contador = 0
    for renglon in data:
        for palabra in renglon.split(' '):
            contador+=1
            print palabra
```

And I call function in main program as:

```
palabras = [] #Create a empty list of words
for palabra in devPalabras("palabras.txt"):
    palabras.append(palabra)
```

And finally, I want to print this list:

```
print palabras
```

Well, I get next Error when I compile my program:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

How can I resolve this?

Comment: And where exactly are you getting this error? Please include the entire message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides of the `return -1`, you are not returning any result, so the call `devPalabras("palabras.txt")` returns `None` by default.

What you could do, is to create a list, let's say `listOfPalabras` and each time you print `palabra`, add it to the list:

```
listOfPalabras = [] # creates a list

for renglon in data:
    for palabra in renglon.split(' '):
        contador+=1
        listOfPalabras.append(palabra) # add each element you want to the list
```

And at the end of the function, you can return the list:

```
return listOfPalabras
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code. 
1) your devPalabras function normally returns None. This is the default if you don't return anything in a function.

2) if `str(nombreF)` is not the proper way to check if it is a string. Use isinstance(nombreF, str)

3) You will have a problem iterating later when your function returns a -1. Raise an exception instead.

4) Simply splitting the line with ' ' will result in the last word ending with a line feed. Strip this linefeed.

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
def devPalabras(nombreF):
    """Receive a file and returns each word in the file
    syntax: palabra.devPalabras(<fichero.txt>)"""

    file=open(nombreF,'r')
    data = file.readlines()
    contador = 0
    for renglon in data:
        for palabra in renglon.split(' '):
            contador+=1
            yield palabra.strip()

palabras = [] #Create a empty list of words
for palabra in devPalabras("palabras.txt"):
    palabras.append(palabra)
```